# How to get rid of this java.io.EOFException?

Tags: java, image, file, exception, applet

I would like to know what's wrong about this code from my java applet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CodeBase: " + getCodeBase());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Earl: " + new URL(getCodeBase(), "../animation/MonkeyAnimX" + String.valueOf(i) + ".jpeg"));
            preparedartwork[i] = getImage(new URL(getCodeBase(), "../animation/MonkeyAnimX" + String.valueOf(i) + ".jpeg"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When the exception is thrown it says:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /var/www/animation/MonkeyAnimX0.jpeg read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:399)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:558)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.<init>(URLImageSource.java:55)
at sun.applet.AppletImageRef.reconstitute(AppletImageRef.java:51)
at sun.misc.Ref.get(Ref.java:64)
at sun.applet.AppletViewer.getCachedImage(AppletViewer.java:395)
at sun.applet.AppletViewer.getImage(AppletViewer.java:390)
at java.applet.Applet.getImage(Applet.java:259)
at MonkeysTyping.init(MonkeysTyping.java:213)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:437)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

To be sure that this exception can't be thrown because of missing rights I changed it so that everybody and -thing has all rights to operate with these files. (-> cmod 777) I got this code from a tutorial so what's wrong?

Comment: Small side note: String.valueOf is not needed when building strings.  This will compile without error: `"../animation/MonkeyAnimX" + i + ".jpeg"`

Comment: It is a java security feature that applets cannot access the files on the hard drive.

Comment: If you open the page via localhost or off the net and the relative paths are correct, it should work.  Java security in regard to applets launched off the *local **disks*** has become so strict that it is not representative of what a sand-boxed applet can do on (when coming from) the net or a local server.  BTW - Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 2):

By default, Applets are not allowed access to filesystem. This is a major security risk as you are exposing your filesystem to external web. You can read more [here](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the file permission but it is due to the security restrictions of applet.  Here is what you need to override the default security policy file used by the SecurityManager.

1) Create a text file (eg. applet.policy)

2) Grant all permissions to the applet

```
 grant {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
  };
```

3) Run the applet with

```
-J-Djava.security.policy=applet.policy
```

Read more about applet security here: **[What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)**